# How to bridge the connections with this component?

Tags: connector, interconnect

I have 1.5mm2 cables to connect together, and up to 1700w 230v total to distribute.

I would like to connect all (9) connectors fo this component ([on Reichelt](https://secure.reichelt.com/fr/fr/prises-bornes-de-c-ble-d-accouplement-multisep-connexion-vis-rnd-205-00349-p170402.html?&nbc=1)):

[image: connector]

Can I have a bridge *like* this one (but *not* this one, which is not correct since it's [for UT6/PT6](https://www.reichelt.com/fr/fr/pont-fixe-10broches-pour-ut6-pt6-fbs-10-8-p209604.html?&trstct=pos_0&nbc=1)):

[image: bridge]

? Which one ?

EDIT:

Or should I switch to a PTFIX system ?

Comment: You can bridge it on the PCB, or with short wires between the screw terminals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That bridge, as you may have surmised, is to connect DIN rail terminal blocks together.  If being able to plug and unplug the wires isn't a concern, a couple of DIN rail terminal blocks connected together like that is probably your best option.  Otherwise, I don't think I've seen many - if any - shorting receptacles for the type of connector you have.  My suggestion is to find the mating connector and if it's a PCB mount, make up a board for it or ideally get a chassis-mount passthrough with wire cages on the other side so you can daisy chain wires from one position to the next.  I suggest the use of dual-entry crimp ferrules.

Answer (score 1):

If the rated current per connection does not in any way exceed 15 amps then it's OK based on [this](https://www.distrelec.biz/Web/Downloads/_t/ds/rnd_797162_eng_tds.pdf) being the appropriate data sheet: -

[image]

Your bridge would have to be rated the same.

Comment: I know this but: which bridge ?

Comment: Be careful about asking for product recommendations as per this site rule: $$$$ *Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.* $$$$ See also [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).